# Flashing nav when hitting the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how I can make the nav-bar flash while hitting the top.

I'm using bootstrap navbar and a jquery script to make it stick to the top while scrolling down but I can't make it flash without jquery looping their 'fadein/out' feature.

Any other options I can use?

```
$(function(){

    var advancedNav = $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > advancedNav ) {
                $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css('display', 'block');
                $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css('width', "100%");          
        } else {
                $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably is because when you set the position to "fixed" you are removing the element from the layout, thus the window scroll changes... what you need to account for is the height of the menu by making it wrapped inside a fixed height div. Try this...

```
<div style="height: 400px">
 <nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu">...</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but the nav is not at the top, I have a header above with a logo inside and I don't want to create another block to hide it. it sticks to the top after you scroll down and you can no longer see the header.

Comment: It doesn't have to be at the top, it just needs to save its spot when it becomes fixed... and the best way to do that is surround it with a static fixed height div, there could be other ways, sometimes you need to calculate the height of the nav, and make the if statement within min and min+height... (instead of just minimum, like your code is doing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$(function(){   

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css('display', 'block');
            $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css('width', "100%");          
    } else {
            $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            $('#custom-bootstrap-menu').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```